# Building a remote command for Elpis in C# through HTTP API

Tags: c#, wcf, http, user-interface, remoting

I am helping to build Elpis, which is an open source pandora music player, built with C# and WPF.

Now what i want is to add an HTTP API so that the user may control the program through a browser, like play/pause, like/dislike the current song.

The point afterwards is to control the program through a mobile device accessing the HTTP API.

How exactly should i build the HTTP API so that it can control it?

Github for the project: https://github.com/adammhaile/Elpis

Comment: Can use describe a scenario of why a user must control a GUI application via HTTP?

Comment: Basically it's a music player, and i want the user to be able to control the player remotely.

Comment: As in, you're sitting at work and you want to pause the song you're playing at home, because you can't hear it anyway? Or do you want to embed a music player on a website? To me it's not very clear what you want exactly...

Comment: The point afterwards is to control the program through a mobile device accessing the HTTP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Kayak(https://github.com/kayak/kayak) for my self-hosted API.

The example of integration can be seen here:
https://github.com/adammhaile/Elpis/blob/master/Elpis/WebInterface.cs

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing why exactly you want the user to control a GUI application via the browser, it's hard to give you good advise.

Assuming you are running your GUI on Windows, take a look at [OWIN](http://owin.org/) and the project [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana). They allow you to easily host HTTP interfaces in your own application.

Comment: And how should i use Katana or OWIN in my project? By creating a library based on this?

Comment: By including the NuGet packages in your project. Use Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost for self-hosting. See here for a tutorial: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for your project but I would suggest using ASP.NET Web API so that you can build backend web services.

Comment: Ok, and how will the C# app communicate with the ASP.NET Web API?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want, assuming you really want to "control the GUI remotely" is to just install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) on your PC and on your mobile device. Then you could remote in and completely control your GUI.

But I what I think you're after is something more like Google Music. Where you can stream your music through the Internet and onto your mobile devices. If this is the case, I recommend you look at the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: The thing is, am i not the only person who will be using this app. Anyone will be able to install it on their own pc.
I just need to have the remote controls available through an API.

Comment: @alexs - Then go with my latter suggestion of using Web API. It sounds exactly like what you need

Comment: OK. But then how will the web api communicate with the program?

Comment: It doesn't. It works the other way around. Your GUI program and mobile apps communicate with the Web Api.

Comment: But that is what i was asking for, to change the playing song with an api access.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to build a web server in C#. You can embed it into your application, and expose parts of your application to HTTP endpoints as an API. You can use the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is part of .NET, and do everything from the ground up yourself. Or you could use something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/), which is a lightweight framework that provides a lot of useful scaffolding like URL routing.